# XML No Longer Read Correctly when Element with Null Attribute is Present

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I have a .xml file which is modified and read in several ways however, when an element with one less attribute than the others is added, a lot of that code no longer works.

The general structure of the .xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Records>
  <Export_Number>1</Export_Number>
  <Current_Activity_Number>4</Current_Activity_Number>
  <Activities>
    <Activity ID="1" Section="Section1" Type="Type1">
      <Date>10/9/2011</Date>
      <Details>Details go here</Details>
    </Activity>
    <Activity ID="2" Section="Unlisted">
      <Date>12/09/2008</Date>
      <Details>Details go here</Details>
      <Notes>Notes go here</Details>
    </Activity>
  </Activities>
</Records>
```

As you can see, the activity entry with the attribute Section = "Unlisted" does not have the attribute 'Type'. This appears to be causing several problems (the problem isn't caused by other entries with both attributes), which are listed below:

**Problem 1** - [InputWorker.cs] the pop-up used for inputting the entry doesn't close automatically because I get a null reference exception for `if (p.Attribute("ID").Value == activityNumber.ToString())`, despite the fact that this attribute exists and the entire entry displays and saves correctly in the XML file. Where p is `foreach (XElement p in lineElement.Element("Activities").Descendants("Activity"))`. There is no fault in lineElement. `Debug.Log (p.Attribute("ID").Value.ToString());` on the line below works correctly, printing the correct number.

**Problem 2** - [ActivityFeed.cs] entries which would usually be displayed on-screen do not display due to this error (before the addition of this entry, they displayed correclty in date order):

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ActivityFeed.<ActivityFeedA>m__0 (System.Xml.Linq.XElement objActs) (at Assets/Scripts/ActivityFeed.cs:137)
System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateSelectIterator>c__Iterator10`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,<>__AnonType0`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.TimeSpan]].MoveNext ()
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>__AnonType0`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.TimeSpan]].AddEnumerable (IEnumerable`1 enumerable) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:128)
```

etc.

The error message highlights the problem as the orderby section of this piece of code:

```
    var all =
        from objActs in xDocument.Element("Records").Element("Activities").Descendants("Activity")
            let actDate = DateTime.Now - DateTime.ParseExact(objActs.Element("Date").Value,"d/M/yyyy",new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
            orderby actDate
            select objActs;
```

**Problem 3** - [Exporter.cs] only gets as far as writing (to .txt) the part before the error occurs. Whilst, as above, it says the error occurs in the date sorting section, it would appear it actually occurs with `file.WriteLine(objActs.Element("Date").Value+lineBreak)`, as all parts of the .txt file written before this appear in the file.

I understand that simply changing my code so that every entry has a type attribute, even if its value is "null" or "n/a", would work. But it feels like there must be a better solution, and I know that there will be situations in future where such a workaround won't be feasible. I've been scratching my head over this for a while now, and I'd be really grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Problem 1: Is *activityNumber* definitely not null?

Comment: @Eraph Nope, it prints to the console twice before being used in the code. I've never seen an entry save with a null value.

Comment: When it breaks on `if (p.Attribute("ID").Value == activityNumber.ToString())`, can you take a look at `p` and make sure it's the kind of element you're expecting?

Comment: @Eraph I print p on the line before the if statement and the ID value of p within it. p before the if loop prints each data entry Activity, inclusive of all attributes and child elements. p inside the if loop prints the correct ID number in cases where the Type attribute is present. Rather strangely, it no longer seems to be causing any of the errors listed above, which I find very confusing.